# Only domain showing up in Google search results

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I have a website that is 6 months old and where all the pages are indexed by Google. The website has about 20 pages and each page targets other keywords. I'm teaching myself SEO so I can live with the fact that my website doesn't show high in Google search as long as it is showing up.

Now the funny thing is that my domain is showing up for multiple keywords in the first 40-50 results on Google search but my other pages aren't showing up anywhere in the results.

`www.example.com` shows up but `www.example.com/test` doesn't show up anywhere.

I tried swapping the content from my homepage to the content from `www.example.com/test` . When I do this, my homepage `www.example.com` is showing up in the search results for the keywords that `www.example.com/test` is targeting.

I tried entering in Google search:  `site:www.example.com` . When I do this, all my pages are displayed including `www.example.com/test`.

When I search in Google for the title of `my www.example.com/test` page, my page isn't showing up. But when I search for the title between quotes like this: **"title of `www.example.com/test`"** it does show up as the only search result.

Any idea what the problem can be?

**EDIT**

Maybe useful to know. I have multiple AdWords Campaigns running. So `www.example.com/test` does receives views in this way.

I have no external links pointing to my homepage nor to any other page on my website. I'm living in a small country where English isn't the native language. This makes it a little harder to find blogs and other websites to link to my website. Taking this into account, I think my webpages should at least show up somewhere in the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to know: site:mysite.com will show indexed pages, however, doing a search for your keywords in no guarantee that your pages will show. If you do not have inbound backlinks and your site is young, you have not built up site rank, page rank (per page), trust rank, citation flow, trust flow, or any other metric. If you are doing on page SEO correctly, Google (and Bing) should be able to correctly index your page, however, with low rank metrics you may never actually appear in the search engine result page (SERP).

Build some backlinks using directories that have rank to each major topic page that is appropriate. DMOZ.org can be difficult, but worth the effort. There are others. Check out http://info.vilesilencer.com/top and pay attention to page rank, alexa rank and age of the directory. Do not spam these, but find some that seem right to create links on for your site.

Also, remember that SEO is a very slow process. Some changes may not be seen for up to a year. Be patient. The more you work on this the more you will see changes over time.

P.S. I think your English is just fine! Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess I'll have to get some backlinks in some way. I'll definitely look at your suggested pages.
Followup question: would it help to setup mini webpages with original content and external links to my website and send adwords traffic to those mini webpages?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by mini web pages. Are you thinking about other small web sites? If that is the case, I would not bother. Too much work. I used to do this, but Google looks for sites owned by single parties (and they are good at it) that link to each other. I would build backlinks the old fashion way. It takes time, but the effects are far better over the long run. Even better, the best SEO tactic is killer content that people will want to link to organically. Hone your craft. The carries the best payoff.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about other small websites. Thank you for your insight. I'll keep it mind and do it the old fashion way.